# Change the access protections of a memory mapping on python (mprotect)

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, ctypes

In versions 2 of python, the `mprotect` function of Linux was exposed on all operating systems through the `ctypes.pythonapi.mprotect`

I need to change the protection of a memory region to `read_write_execute` (1 | 2 | 4) through python

**How can I do this in a cross platform way?**

```
>>> read_write_execute = 1 | 2 | 4
>>> ctypes.pythonapi.mprotect(address, size, read_write_execute)
```

Other ways:

**Linux**

```
import ctypes, mmap

libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'), use_errno=True)
mmap_function = libc.mmap
mmap_function.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
mmap_function.argtype = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_size_t]

code_address = mmap_function(None, code_size, mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE | mmap.PROT_EXEC, mmap.MAP_ANON | mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0)
```

**Windows**

```
import ctypes

PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000
MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000

VirtualAlloc_function = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc
VirtualAlloc_function.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
VirtualAlloc_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong]

code_address = VirtualAlloc_function(None, code_size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
```

Comment: You are talking about "previous version" but you did not give any version number for "previous" or "recent".

Comment: Thank you, edited

Comment: On a Unix system, `ctypes.pythonapi` is just accessing the process globals. It's from `ctypes.PyDLL(None)`, i.e. `dlopen(NULL, ...)`. It has nothing to do with Python's C API, in which case using it for a function like `mprotect` is unnecessarily holding the GIL (global interpreter lock).

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for the clarification. I'll see how best to change the description.

Comment: In Unix, libc should be loaded via `libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'), use_errno=True)`. (This doesn't work in Windows for Python 3.5+, since switching to the Universal C runtime and API sets, in which case `find_library('c')` returns `None`. It also doesn't work reliably when Python 2.7 is embedded due to msvcr90.dll requiring a SxS activation context.)

Comment: Thank you, edited